# Nginx + Wordpress permisions settings

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, permissions, nfs, wordpress

I'm experimenting some troubles with a wordpress installation backed on nginx. The architecture is held in amazon and is the following:

EC2 Nginx 1.2.4 + php-fpm Server 
EC2 NFS Server
RDS mysql

The nginx reads the site files from a nfs partition at /mnt/sharedpool/blog

The fstab config is:

compute-1.amazonaws.com:/mnt/sharedpool       /mnt/sharedpool nfs rw,relatime 0 0

The nfs server /etc/exports config:

/mnt/sharedpool ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com(rw,sync)

The nginx user and group are set to www-data:www-data and the root directive of the site is set to /mnt/sharedpool/blog

I downloaded the last version of wordpress and sucessfully installed it. The thing is that after logged in, I'm getting 403 Forbidden.. I think is should be a wordpress setting, given the fact that I can create and call a phpinfo() in the same directory.

UPDATED:

### Nginx Server Config:

user www-data www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

```
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

### Nginx site config:

server {
        listen   80;
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

```
    root /mnt/sharedpool/blog;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            #autoindex on;
    #       allow 127.0.0.1;
    #       allow ::1;
    #       deny all;
    }


    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh sorry, here:

2012/11/18 00:41:16 [error] 847#0: *3 directory index of "/mnt/sharedpool/blog/" is forbidden, client: 190.17.2.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "23.23.141.xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like nginx isn't quite sure what index file to load for your site. Since it's a PHP-based site (WordPress), this should be `index.php`. But your `index` directive reads:

```
    index index.html index.htm;
```

I would change this to:

```
    index index.php;
```